# How to push tool to use openvpn client?

Tags: openvpn, vpn

How to use openvpn client only for specific tool (f.e. for curl)?
All other tools should not use vpn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two possibilities.

**separate UID and advanced routing**

If you can run this tool under a dedicated UID (i.e. nothing else uses it) then you can use `iptables` to mark the packets for this UID (`--set-mark`). This mark can be used in `ip rule` for selecting a separate routing table.

**separate namespace and advanced routing**

You can set up a separate network namespace (`man ip-netns`). You can connect it to your regular namespace with a veth pair. Then you set up routing rules for packets from this veth and run the tool within this namespace:

```
ip netns exec toolns tool
```